# How to clone select box with different name value in CakePHP?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I would like to know how to clone and append select box with same options but different name in CakePHP style. Also after the cloning,I want it chained each others .

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide your tried code for solution.